# Twitter Bootstrap Twipsy - Hovering above the tooltip

Tags: jquery, hover, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use [Twitter Bootstrap Twipsy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#twipsy) as a **hovering** tooltip with a link inside the tooltip.

The problem is that when the mouse cursor leaves the element then the tooltip disappears and users can't reach the link inside the tooltip (take a look at the [Demo](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#twipsy) and see that you can't put your mouse cursor on the twipsy black bubble as it disappear).

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: The Problem is: When should the tooltip disappear, if it includes a link. One way is, to disable the `eventOut` completely

Comment: @Sn0opy but if I disable the `eventOut` event then it will not disappear forever, and I do want it disappear if the mouse cursor is not above the tagged element or above the tooltip itself.

Comment: I think this is a bigger change to the framework / js extension. I recommend you to create a new issue / RFE on the project site: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues. There are many more people working with bootstrap, who know the code, how it works and how to extend it.

Comment: Im having a similiar problem.  When I firebugged it I noticed that when you unhover from the twipsy icons it is leaving its transparent divs on top of things makng the icon default to curson instead of the pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find it difficult to believe that one of the creators of bootstrap told you this wasn't possible, as it most definitely is - It just takes a bit of tinkering.

Here is the solution in coffeescript and jquery, tested and working:

```
timer = null
el = null
el2 = null
$('[rel=twipsy]').live
  mouseenter: ->
    $('.twipsy').remove()
    $(this).twipsy('show')
  , mouseleave: ->
    el = $(this)
    timer = setTimeout((-> 
      el.twipsy('hide')
      $('body .twipsy:last-child').remove()
    ), 10)

$('.twipsy').live
  mouseenter: ->
    clearTimeout(timer)
    el2 = $(this)
    el2.css 'z-index', 1000 if el2.hasClass 'in'
  , mouseleave: ->
    timer = setTimeout((->
      el.twipsy('hide')
      el2.css 'z-index', 1
      $('body .twipsy:last-child').remove()
    ), 10)
```

If you are working on an application that gets heavy traffic, has to work in old browsers or old computers, or otherwise is very performance-reliant, I would highly recommend rolling your own solution here, as using a lot of live handlers isn't really a great idea. But for something small/normal, this works just fine. I've only found one small very strange bug that can come up (although it is rare) if you hover in a particular way. The overlap issue is solved by z-index manipulation.

If you need this is in vanilla javascript, just paste it into the "try coffeescript" console at http://coffeescript.org/ and it will compile for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really needed here was Twitter Popovers.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers

Tooltips are used just for displaying some information(that's why it is called a tool 'tip').
Where as, if you need user interactions, you need to use the Popovers.

Now here a question may arise on the usability point that why to increase a user click if we can achieve the same using tooltip hover. But this gives the user the control of the time he wants for making the interaction. So in my opinion, it improves Usability. You cannot tellthe user to click a link within 2 seconds(the timeout set) or it will go away. Its not good for usability

I appreciate the work done for this answer, and though the answer is correct, the solution isnt.

Hope I have made myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you read my comment above and seem to be having the same problem, this is what worked for me.

You can set a delay on the animation of around 300ms which it actually mentions doing in the documentation.

Comment: It wouldn't help since it will fade out after eventually. One of the creators of the Twitter Bootstrap toolkit [told me](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/572) that what I wanted to do is impossible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the trigger of the twipsy to 'manual' and then bind events such as 'mouseenter' to a function that uses a timer to wait a few seconds before closing. Try this:

```
$(element).twipsy({
    trigger:'manual'
});
$(element).bind('mouseover',function(){
    $(element).twipsy('show');
    if ( $(element).data('timerIsGoing') !== true ) {
        $(element).data('timerIsGoing',true);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(element).twipsy('hide');
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

This will give the user 2 seconds to click the link.

Also, I just noticed your issue with the fact that there might be other tooltips nearby that get overlapped. On mouseover You could trigger a custom event that hides all other active tooltips... just a thought

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem, but I had both jQuery.js and Prototype.js loaded.  Preventing prototype.js to load fixes the problem.